# Insertar multiples archivos blob (fotos) en una columna de una tabla oracle sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper, blob

estoy actualmente en un problema que no puedo solucionar, tengo una tabla habitación a la que le he creado una columna adicional del tipo EMPTY_BLOB()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la cual necesito agregar por cada fila, una foto con el mismo nombre del campo "tipo_habitacion" 
para hacer ese proceso, estoy usando un cursor para recorrer todos los datos de esta tabla habitación y comparando el nombre del archivo al tipo de la habitación.

```
   `for r in cur_hab
    loop 
    begin

    insert into habitacion (FOTO)
    values (EMPTY_BLOB())
    Returning FOTO into v_img;

    v_nombref:= to_char(r.tipo_habitacion||'.jpg');

    v_bfile := bfilename('img', v_nombref);
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(v_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
    DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(v_img, v_bfile, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_bfile));
    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(v_bfile);
    commit;
    exit when cur_hab%notfound;`
```

también estoy capturando errores mediante excepciones, pero el código me devuelve el error "TO_MANY_ROWS" por cada dato comparado

```
exception when TOO_MANY_ROWS then
insert into error_proceso_foto
values (SEQ_ERROR.NEXTVAL, r.tipo_habitacion , sysdate);
dbms_output.put_line('muchas filas');
when NO_DATA_FOUND then
insert into error_proceso_foto
values(SEQ_ERROR.NEXTVAL, r.tipo_habitacion , sysdate);
dbms_output.put_line('no hay datos');
end;    
end loop;
```

me he asegurado que el directorio esta creado, y que tengo los permisos necesarios para ello, además de que el directorio efectivamente tiene las fotos con los nombres necesarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]